# handling jwt token through express returns error "const token = req.cookies.auth; [0] ^ [0] [0] ReferenceError: req is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I am trying to complete jwt sign in I am trying to create the jwt token in login.Then I am trying to use it within my user-questions route.

I am using a react front end.

Is this the correct way to do so?

I am currently getting error

```
const token = req.cookies.auth;
[0]               ^
[0]
[0] ReferenceError: req is not defined
```

Below is my routes login code which assigns the token once the my sql server return that the values for email and password exist. User-questions tries to use this jwt. and I have also included how the token is verfied in a function

Verfiy users

```
app.get("/user-questions", verifyToken, function(req, res) {
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // decode token
    if (token) {
      jwt.verify(token, "secret", function(err, token_data) {
        if (err) {
          console.info("token did not work");
          return res.status(403).send("Error");
        } else {
          req.user_data = token_data;
          sql.connect(config, function(err) {
            if (err) console.log(err);

            // create Request object
            var request = new sql.Request();

            // query to the database and get the records
            request.execute("dbo.ViewQuestions", function(err, recordset) {
              if (err) console.log(err);

              // send records as a response

              res.json(recordset);
              next();
            });
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.info("no token");
      console.log("no token");
      return res.status(403).send("No token");
    }
  });
});
```

Login route

```
app.post("/login", async (req, response) => {
  try {
    await sql.connect(config);

    var request = new sql.Request();
    var Email = req.body.email;
    var Password = req.body.password;

    console.log({ Email, Password });

    request.input("Email", sql.VarChar, Email);
    request.input("Password", sql.VarChar, Password);

    var queryString =
      "SELECT * FROM TestLogin WHERE email = @Email AND password = @Password";

    //"SELECT * FROM RegisteredUsers WHERE email = @Email AND Password = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @Password + 'skrrt')";

    const result = await request.query(queryString);

    if (result.recordsets[0].length > 0) {
      console.info("/login: login successful..");
      console.log(req.body);

      token = jwt.sign(
        { Email },
        "secretkey",
        { expiresIn: "30s" },
        (err, token) => {
          res.json({
            token
          });
          res.cookie("auth", token);
          res.send("ok");
        }
      );
    } else {
      console.info("/login: bad creds");
      response.status(400).send("Incorrect email and/or Password!");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Err: ", err);
    response.status(500).send("Check api console.log for the error");
  }
});
```

Verify users

```
// Verify Token
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  // Get auth header value
  const bearerHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
  // Check if bearer is undefined
  if (typeof bearerHeader !== "undefined") {
    // Split at the space
    const bearer = bearerHeader.split(" ");
    // Get token from array
    const bearerToken = bearer[1];
    // Set the token
    req.token = bearerToken;
    // Next middleware
    next();
  } else {
    // Forbidden
    res.sendStatus(403);
  }
}
```

Please advise if this in theory should work. And if not please advise how to resolve.

EDIT :

The error has been resolved however now simply my jwt tokens to do not work. As when logged in and I manually route to user-questions it does not load the component and within the console it says 403 not available (this is set in the code when the jwt token is not working).

UPDATE:

How would I include

```
 ['authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
```

into

```
 handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.email.length < 8 || this.state.password.length < 8) {
      alert(`please enter the form correctly `);
    } else {
      const data = { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password };

      fetch("/login", {
        method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",

        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
        // .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log("Success:", data);


        })

        .catch(error => {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: the line that is causing your error is not in your `/user-questions` route or any of your code snippets, can you post the code that line is from?

Comment: my apologies it was not that line I had defined " const token = req.cookies.auth;" above user-questions. I have deleted that and the error is not persisting. However the jwt token does not load as when going to user-questions it does not load the component

Comment: any idea why this is not working ?

Comment: Of course it's not working, you are defining a middleware after the route `/user-questions` is reached. Your code says : First, the user must reach the route `/user-questions`. Then, and after then, do I register the JWT verifying middleware that will get executed when the route is reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of errors with your code:

- In your `/login` route:

  - You are trying to set the "auth" cookie after the response is being sent
  - You are trying to send a response twice, once via `res.json` and once via `res.send`
  - You are assigning to a `token` variable that no longer exists (`token = jwt.sign(...)`)
- In your `verifyToken` method:

  - This method is only verifying that the request has a token set, it's not validating or decoding it. I would consider moving your `jwt.verify()` call to this method.
- In your `/user-questions` route:

  - You're calling `app.use` inside of `app.get`, when both of these are intended to be called at the root level. Remove your `app.use` call.
  - You need to grab `token` from the request, ex. `const { token } = req;`
  - You are sending a response via `res.json()`, but you are still calling `next()` afterwards. From the [Express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html):

    > **If the current middleware function does not end the request-response cycle**, it must call next() to pass control to the next middleware function.

---

This is how I would make these changes:

- `/login` route:

```js
app.post("/login", async (req, response) => {
  try {
    await sql.connect(config);

    var request = new sql.Request();
    var Email = req.body.email;
    var Password = req.body.password;

    console.log({ Email, Password });

    request.input("Email", sql.VarChar, Email);
    request.input("Password", sql.VarChar, Password);

    var queryString =
      "SELECT * FROM TestLogin WHERE email = @Email AND password = @Password";

    //"SELECT * FROM RegisteredUsers WHERE email = @Email AND Password = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @Password + 'skrrt')";

    const result = await request.query(queryString);

    if (result.recordsets[0].length > 0) {
      console.info("/login: login successful..");
      console.log(req.body);

      jwt.sign(
        { Email },
        "secretkey",
        { expiresIn: "30s" },
        (err, token) => res.cookie('auth', token).json({ token })
      );
    } else {
      console.info("/login: bad creds");
      response.status(400).send("Incorrect email and/or Password!");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Err: ", err);
    response.status(500).send("Check api console.log for the error");
  }
});
```

- `verifyToken` method:

```js
// Verify Token
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  // Get auth header value
  const bearerHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
  // Check if bearer is undefined
  if (typeof bearerHeader !== "undefined") {
    // Split at the space
    const bearer = bearerHeader.split(" ");
    // Get token from array
    const bearerToken = bearer[1];

    // verify the token and store it
    jwt.verify(bearerToken, "secret", function(err, decodedToken) {
      if (err) {
        console.info("token did not work");
        return res.status(403).send("Error");
      }

      // Set the token
      req.token = bearerToken;
      req.decodedToken = decodedToken;

      next();
    });
  } else {
    // Forbidden
    res.sendStatus(403);
  }
}
```

- `/user-questions` route:

```js
app.get("/user-questions", verifyToken, function(req, res) {
  // if a request has made it to this point, then we know they have a valid token
  // and that token is available through either req.token (encoded)
  // or req.decodedToken

  sql.connect(config, function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();

    // query to the database and get the records
    request.execute("dbo.ViewQuestions", function(err, recordset) {
      if (err) console.log(err);

      // send records as a response

      res.json(recordset);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Okay thank you for your time I am a bit clueless as of right now. If you want to show any examples I will not stop you ,but i think you have answered the question so I will set this as the answer

Comment: You are a star ! However this does not work for me still I am still recievng a 403 error within the console.

Comment: without having seen your front end code, I would assume it's because you're not sending your token (the response body from your `POST /login` request) as part of your request `authorization` header. make sure for any requests you send that you're setting `request.headers['authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;`.

Comment: I think you may be onto something so far I have this headers: {
          Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })

Comment: I have updated the answer for you if you have time to help